# How to align elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am unable to align the elements in one line. I am using `display: inline-block` but for some reason it is not taking the affect. I am using `DataTables`.I want the buttons (images) to be aligned with the box showing the page number.

[image]

CSS

```
.dataTables_paginate input {
 width: 8%; 
 height: 8%; 
 padding-bottom: 0.2px;
 display: inline-block; 
 font: normal 11px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 1.5em;
 padding: 0.5em 1em;
 margin-left: 2px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none !important;
 cursor: pointer;
 *cursor: hand;
 color: #333 !important;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 2px;
}
```

My Jquery

```
var table = $('#esignTable').DataTable({"sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">',
      pagingType: 'input',
      pageLength: 5,
      language: {
        "sEmptyTable": " ",
        oPaginate: {
            "sNext": '<img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg">',
            "sPrevious": '<img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg">',
            "sFirst": '<img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg">',
            "sLast": '<img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg">',
        }
      }   
    });
```

Comment: Did you try vertical-align;middle; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to `.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button`

or use flexbox for paginate

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `padding-bottom: 0.2px;` to `padding-bottom: 0.5em;` they have different padding at bottom:

```css
.dataTables_paginate input {
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal 11px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin-left: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  *cursor: hand;
  color: #333 !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give your dataTables block such styles:

```
    .dataTable-block {`dispaly: flex;align-items: center;}
```